# Find nearest set of values to a given value within an array

Tags: matlab

```
A = 
0.75
0.6
0.62
0.51
0.53
0.48
```

Within such an array, how can one calculate the indices of x number of values closest to a given number? For example:

```
x = 0.5 %Given number 
y = 3; %Number of values closest to (x) to extract
```

Here we wish to extract the three closest values to 0.5 - 0.51, 0.53 and 0.48.

```
[~,I] = min(abs(data-b));
c = data(I);
```

Is what I have thus far but this only extracts a single value - the absolute closest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
A = [0.75
0.6
0.62
0.51
0.53
0.48];

x = 0.5 %Given number 
y = 3; %Number of values closest to (x) to extract

[~,c] = sort(abs(A-x));
yclosest=A(c(1:y));
```

This uses the second output of [`sort`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) to index the original array `A`. First you subtract the number `x` from the array `A` and take the absolute value, as you had, then you sort that and take the lowest `y` numbers and use those to index `A`.

Answer (score 4):

Sorting the absolute differences and choosing the three values that minimize this difference is the most canonical way to do it.... in fact, that's what I recommend.

However for the sake of completeness, if you can use toolboxes consider using [`knnsearch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/knnsearch.html) from the Statistics Toolbox and return the `k=3` closest points. The output of `knnsearch` gives you the **indices** of the closest points.  To find the actual points, index into `A` after:

```
A = [0.75
0.6
0.62
0.51
0.53
0.48];

x = 0.5;
y = 3;

IDX = knnsearch(A, x, 'K', y);
out = A(IDX);
```

We get:

```
>> out = A(IDX)

out =

    0.5100
    0.4800
    0.5300
```